# Custom navigation optimisation issue

Tags: flutter, provider

I'm using a custom navigation for my project by keeping a `List<Widget>` for pages in a provider class, and using the last element of that list as page to display.

The provider has methods for push (which adds a widget into the list) and pop (removes the last element of the list). And each method has `notifyListener()`

Everytime I push a widget into the list I'm able to see that widget as the page infront and calling  `pop()` takes me back to the previous page.

here is the provider class,

```
class PaginationProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Widget> _pagesStack = [const FirstPage()];

  List<Widget> get pagesStack=>_pagesStack;

  push(Widget page) {
    _pagesStack.add(page);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  pop(){
    _pagesStack.removeLast();
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

and the main page part,

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<PaginationProvider>(
        builder: (context, paginationProvider, _) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: paginationProvider.pagesStack.last,
      );
    });
  }
```

The problem is that every time I go back to a page that page getting rebuilt as if it is being called for the first time. Which causes API calls associated with that page to recall.

I tried making those page `stateful` and `stateless` but no effect.
How can I save the state of each page even after a new page is added to the list and removed.